# Ubuntu 15.04 suspend halt

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, suspend, power-management, lenovo

## I have

- laptop Lenovo E540 with SSD + HDD
- Ubuntu 15.04 on SSD with UEFI, kernel  `3.19.0-26-generic`
- Nvidia GeForce 840M with driver 346.59

## The problem

When I suspend the laptop, i hear HDD heads parking, display goes black (not sure, if it really turns off), power LED starts blink as the laptop is in suspend mode, but the fan is still working and never stops. After this bugged suspend, the laptop halts and does not respond on keys, mouse clicks, power button. The only way to make it alive - to make the power reset.

## I tried

This - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290

Run `umount -a` before suspend

Remove all external USB devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug posted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1340376

Workaround: To turn disable USB3 in BIOS

Solution: to update BIOS to version 2.20 [download link](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e540)